# код работает через раз

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq
url = 'http://requests.task-sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/data/ed148e0621fd22140747d13da484ba01'
data_1 = rq.options(url, params={'page' : '1'})
open('data_1.csv', 'wb').write(data_1.content)
data_1 = pd.read_csv('data_1.csv')
data_1
```

Как можно исправить проблему, что код работает непостоянно

Comment: какую?) ошибку приведите

Comment: ooops или Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'ooops :('

Comment: я бы посоветовал автору сайта еще убрать из конфигурации debug=True пока кто-нибудь не сломал сайт

Comment: да его там уже задолбили волной со стековерфлоу)

Answer (score 1):

Cоздатель сайта решил не отдавать вам данные или не смог их отдать, а выдал `ooops :(`

Comment: но иногда же я их получаю

Comment: сервер не справляется или антибот срабатывает через раз. Ваш код не виноват.